# rc.local on Ubuntu server 16.04 executed twice

Tags: boot

I put the following line in the `/etc/rc.local` on my Ubuntu Server 16.04 and reboot, found the command executed correctly after boot but then after 2 minutes it executed again (checked with `ps -ef`):

```
screen -d -m /home/user/myApp
```

also have try to put this line to a upstart conf file in `/etc/init`, but same result, got 2 process started with 2 mins time shift

How can I prevent this happening?

Comment: What is the content of *myApp* ?

Comment: that's a simple task (even just print current every 10 seconds)
and I follow the answer from 
https://superuser.com/questions/1164311/how-to-prevent-etc-rc-local-from-running-twice
can get debug output the rc.local executed twice just 2 mins after it's first run